# Get method in retrofit Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working on a android studio project and I am using retrofit to get something from web api. I made an Login screen with get retrofit and it also get id together, it looks like this `{"Results":[{"Id":1.0,"username":"test","password":"Test"}]}` and I used get request with this web api `http://XXX.XX.XX.X/webapi/api/user?username=test&password=test`. How do I get the Id and insert into TextView or Intent to other activity?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button loginButton;

    EditText edUsername, edPassword;
 
    TextView tvId

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        edUsername=findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        edPassword=findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        tvId=findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    String message="Please insert Username and Password";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                    loginRequest.setUsername(edUsername.getText().toString());
                    loginRequest.setPassword(edPassword.getText().toString());
                    loginUser(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loginUser(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getService().loginUser(edUsername.getText().toString(), edPassword.getText().toString());
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse=response.body();
                    loginResponse.getId(tvId); <--- does not work to get Id with username and password
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    String message = "No User Found";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                String message="Incorrect Username or Password";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give the code of getId() function. you set your textview as parameter. I am confused so if you can give the function codes too, I will try to help. thanks